# how can i know the path of a file created by os.makedirs() and store it in a variable for later use?

Tags: python, python-docx, python-os

i want to build a function that convert names from csv to a document in word by docx library and i want to create an empty file with os.makedirs(), the file is created but i cant get its path to later join path with word document to save the document in that file
here is my code:

```
    import docx
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    import os
    from docx2pdf import convert
    from pathlib import Path
def auto_fill(x,y):
    database=pd.read_csv(x)
    df=pd.DataFrame(database)
    df=df.dropna(axis=0)
    targeted_doc=docx.Document(y)
    date = datetime.date(datetime.now())

    strdate = date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    path = strdate
    newfile = os.makedirs(path)
    newfile_path = path(newfile)
    for i in range(len(df.Name)+1):
        for n in range (len(targeted_doc.paragraphs)+1):
            if targeted_doc.paragraphs[n].text=="Name of trainee":
                name=targeted_doc.paragraphs[n].runs[0].text=df.at[i,'Name']

        for m in range(len(targeted_doc.paragraphs) + 1):
            if targeted_doc.paragraphs[m].text == "tissue date":
                date = targeted_doc.paragraphs[n].runs[0].text = strdate
        for l in range(len(targeted_doc.paragraphs) + 1):
            if targeted_doc.paragraphs[n].text == "tserial number":
                sr_num = targeted_doc.paragraphs[l].runs[0].text = df.at[i, 'serial number']

        name_of_file = (f"{df.at[i, 'Name']}.docx")
        outputdoc=targeted_doc.save(name_of_file)
        path_of_document=path(outputdoc)
        completesave = os.path.join(path_of_document, name_of_file)
        convert(path_of_document,newfile_path+f"{name_of_file}.pdf")

auto_fill("database.csv","01.docx")
```

Comment: You already know the path, it's stored in the variable `path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't change the location, you can use the same `path`. If you change the location, you can get the path from your script using `os.getcwd()` and join it wiht the `path` using `os.path.join()`

You can store the result of `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path)` to a variable and use it later. You can compose that absolute path before creating the file, so you'll have the entire path

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish, then just use the `path` variable you made earlier. Since you used `os.makedirs(path)`, then the path to that would just be the `path` object.